# How to make url's friendly with asp mvc routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I am using asp mvc3.I want to learn how to make my Urls friendly.
this is my repository layer:

```
public Section GetBySectionId(int sectionId)
{
    return context.Sections.Include("Groups").Include("Partners").Where(s => s.SectionId == sectionId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And this is the application layer:

```
public Section GetBySectionId(int sectionId)
{
    return sectionRepo.GetBySectionId(sectionId);
}
```

And this is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var section = Mapper.Map<SectionViewModel>(sectionApp.GetBySectionId(id));
    return View(section);
}
```

Now for example if I go to a section's details with id=3 the browser url would change to `~/Section/Details/3` but I want it to be `~/Section in persian/Details in persian/My section name`.How can I do this.How to work with asp mvc routing?

Comment: can you please describe that "Section in persian" "Details in persian"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851730/mvc-route-actionlink-url-use-name-instead-of-id

Comment: I mean instead of seeing ~/Section/Details/3 I want to see     ~/موبایل/جزییات/بخش.I mean the meaning of section and details in persian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change in your Routing like this

```
routes.MapRoute(..., "{controller}/{action}/{id}", ...);
```

... and change it to something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(..., "{controller}/{action}/{name}", ...);
```

Then have your action take the name instead of the ID:

```
Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new {item.Name})
```